# Handle stale desktop lock files after emacs/system crash

Tags: start-up, desktop

If Emacs or the system crashes when [`desktop-save-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) is active, Emacs leaves a stale desktop lock file. The next time the desktop is loaded (from another Emacs process ID), loading is interrupted with a question:

> Warning: desktop file appears to be in use by PID xxx.
>   Using it may cause conflicts. Use it anyway? (y or n)

even if if the process with PID xxx (substitute a process ID for xxx) is no longer alive.

Here is minimal example: First run `emacs -Q -l init.el` with the following init file (`init.el`):

```
(require 'desktop)
(let ((dir "/home/hakon/my-emacs-desktop-test"))
  (setq desktop-path (list dir))
  (desktop-save-mode 1))
```

Then open some new buffers, and exit emacs. This will generate a new desktop file. Now, create a fake lock file (with process ID 999 or substitute any integer that does not represent a running process ID)

```
echo "999" > /home/hakon/my-emacs-desktop-test/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

and rerun Emacs with a new init file `emacs -Q -l init2.el`, where `init2.el` is:

```
(require 'desktop)
(let ((dir "/home/hakon/my-emacs-desktop-test"))
  (setq desktop-path (list dir))
  (desktop-save-mode 1))
(desktop-read)
```

This should bring up the warning (*"desktop file appears to be in use"*).

How can we get rid of this message?

Comment: On Windows 10 I get a stale desktop lock file just by shutting down normally with an open Emacs 28.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if the process is still alive using system command `ps -p $PID`, then delete the lock file if the process is not still alive. The following modification of `init2.el` above shows how this can be done from within Emacs. Note that I use two private functions from `desktop.el`, namely `desktop-owner` and `desktop-full-lock-name`.

```
(require 'desktop)
(defun my-remove-stale-lock-file (dir)
  (let ((pid (desktop-owner dir)))
    (when pid
      (let ((infile nil)
            (destination nil)
            (display nil))
        (unless (= (call-process "ps" infile destination display "-p"
                                 (number-to-string pid)) 0)
          (let ((lock-fn (desktop-full-lock-name dir)))
            (delete-file lock-fn)))))))

(let ((dir "/home/hakon/my-emacs-desktop-test"))
  (my-remove-stale-lock-file dir)
  (setq desktop-path (list dir))
  (desktop-save-mode 1))
(desktop-read)
```

Now using this approach, the lock file should not exist at the time when `desktop-read` is called, and the warning is no longer issued.

**Note**:

There is also a variable `desktop-load-locked-desktop` in `desktop.el`. Setting this variable to `t` will load a desktop even if the lock file exist (and prevent the warning). But as far as I can see this does not check if the process is alive or not. So it might not be such a good idea in the case there is an alive Emacs process using the same desktop.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the accepted answer, this two line solution loads for me without a locked prompt.

```
 (setq desktop-load-locked-desktop t)
 (call-interactively 'desktop-read t (vector "~/.emacs.d/desktops/" t))
```

Comment: per the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) setting `desktop-load-locked-desktop` to `t` just ignores the lock file.

Comment: I only have a `~/.emacs.desktop` file not a `~/emacs.d/desktops/` directory.  Modified code accordingly, and seem to work. Using Emacs 28.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This version checks to see if the process in the lock file is still alive, but *also* that it is an `emacs` process, and it does it without calling out to `ps` since we can do that directly in elisp. Just ensure this block comes after you've set your `desktop-dirname` in your `init.el`:

```elisp
;; Ensure we don't skip restoring the desktop after emacs has crashed
(require 'desktop)
(unless (equal (alist-get 'comm (process-attributes (or (desktop-owner) 0))) "emacs")
  (delete-file (desktop-full-lock-name)))
(desktop-read)
```

I tested this by launching a second `emacs` instance, and it properly warns that the desktop file appears to be in use. And when I `pkill -9 emacs`, leaving the lock file in place, I am able to successfully relaunch `emacs` and it deletes the lock file and recreates it without any input.